# Hiding startup items - key logger

Tags: startup, installed-programs

I'm a bit worried about what my daughter is getting up to online (think she might be bullying someone online). I downloaded a very simple .exe key logger file that opens a temp folder on the C: drive and auto logs all keystrokes.

I tried putting it into the startup folder and setting the attributes of the file as hidden, so she cant see it in the startup folder, but this stops the program from functioning altogether.

Is there a way of getting the program to run (hidden) where she can't find it?
I'm not a very advanced computer user - although she is - and I need a foolproof method.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: You should probably try talking to her instead of installing spyware on the computer she uses?

Comment: Yeah - we have tried, and we have limited her access to the pc- but she is going through a difficult stage and everything we say is wrong- believe me I wouldnt do this unless it was the LAST option

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is an Ubuntu question, you are describing trying to use a Windows program. but ---

I remember that managing a young person's use of the Internet can be difficult.

We made a rule that he could only connect when we were home, and only on the computer in the family room.

When he broke the rule I set up the computer so that it couldn't be used on the Internet unless I unlocked its software (after we grounded him for a while). The easiest way to stop the Internet connection would be to physically lock up the cable/adsl modem you need to connect to the Internet.

The problem is that your youngster may move to a neighbor's computer so you will need to contact her friends' parents for such a rule to be effective.

I don't recommend that you do anything sneaky since that's exactly what you don't want her to be--and you don't want to try to win an escalating computer technology battle with your kid, either. That's not your strength. Your strength can be disagreeable consequences for misbehaviour and enforcement steps you take that she can't predict.

Answer (score 0):

If she uses a desktop computer, and the keyboard uses a USB connection, you can buy a key logging device that will plug into the back of the computer. Plugging it in back there will hide it. To know if this will work, just follow the keyboard cable to the back of the computer. Pay attention to where it connects so you can put it back into the same hole. Briefly unplug it to look at the connection type. If it has a flat connection like the one in the product described below, this device will work for you. If it has a round connection, this will not work.

http://www.keyghost.com/USB-Keylogger.htm

Comment: Wouldn't unplug  the thing just defeat it's purpose?..

Comment: Sure, but who looks at the back of a desktop computer? Many users NEVER do, once the computer has been setup. The device that I linked to is handy because it requires no software, and no technical experience to use.